# How to override slot from native Qt class (QStatusBar) so that the overridden implementations get called by other methods?

Tags: qt, pyqt5, pyside2

I am trying to override the clearMessage slot/method from QStatusBar in PySide2.

I have a custom class inheriting from QStatusBar, which re-implements showMessage and clearMessage methods.

```py
class MyStatus(QtWidgets.QStatusBar):
    def showMessage(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyStatus, self).showMessage(*args, **kwargs)
        print('Showing message')

    def clearMessage(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyStatus, self).clearMessage(*args, **kwargs)
        print('Clearing message')
```

According to the c++ source code I could find for the QStatusBar, when calling `showMessage` with a timeout argument, the clearMessage slot should be called when the timer expires:

```cpp
void QStatusBar::showMessage(const QString &message, int timeout)
{
    Q_D(QStatusBar);
    if (timeout > 0) {
        if (!d->timer) {
            d->timer = new QTimer(this);
            connect(d->timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(clearMessage()));
        }
        d->timer->start(timeout);
    } else if (d->timer) {
        delete d->timer;
        d->timer = nullptr;
    }
    if (d->tempItem == message)
        return;
    d->tempItem = message;
    hideOrShow();
}
```

While the message does clear at the end of the timer, the print line I added in the method is not being printed, which makes me believe that either:

- it's still executing the base class's clearMessage method
- maybe the source code I found is for a different version of Qt, and PySide2 5.12.6 doesn't call the method at all

I need to make sure my custom clearMessage is being called any time the message gets cleared, whether it's manually(currently fine) or via a timer or other reason.

I could re-implement my own Qtimer and make sure I'm catching any other method which might call clearMessage, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something obvious which is preventing me from overriding the method properly.

Comment: The two slots you're reimplementing aren't *virtual*, so Qt won't call them internally. (Protected methods also behave the same way, but that isn't relevant here).

Comment: I'm pretty new to C++, and not fully aware of the intricacies of virtual methods, I'll read into that. Do you think that means I need to re-implement the QTimer logic?

Comment: @ErwanLeroy simply put, a virtual method is a method that will always be called implicitly even when it's overridden: it's the case of event handlers (like `mousePressEvent()`) or function that are expected to be overridden for proper implementation of subclasses. `clearMessage()` is not virtual, so even if you try override, that override will only work when you explicitly call it.

Comment: I don't see much point in reproducing the same timer logic, and hacking the internal timer seems needlessly fragile. It's simpler to just create a permanent one-shot timer (i.e. `self._timer = QTimer(singleShot=True, timeout=self.clearMessage)`) and then do `super().showMessage(message); if timeout > 0: self._timer.start(timeout)`.

Comment: Would have to do a little bit of cleanup in case showMessage or clearMessage is called before the timer has timed out, but also possible. I ended up using a different way (I could swear I posted it as another answer, but now it's nowhere to be seen). Instead of re-implementing clearMessage I handle what I needed to handle in another slot which I've linked to the messageChanged signal, and that does the job nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`clearMessage()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstatusbar.html#clearMessage) is not listed as *virtual*, which means that overriding has no effect in the "internal" behavior, and it would only work when explicitly called from *your* code.

Since `clearMessage()` is actually called from Qt only from the QTimer created in `showMessage()`, then a possible workaround is to check for the *latest* QTimer child object created after calling the base implementation, disconnect its `timeout` signal and connect it again to *your* slot:

```py
class MyStatusBar(QStatusBar):
    def showMessage(self, message, timeout=0):
        super().showMessage(message, timeout)
        if timeout:
            timer = self.findChildren(QTimer)[-1]
            timer.timeout.disconnect()
            timer.timeout.connect(self.clearMessage)

    def clearMessage(self):
        super().clearMessage()
        print('my clearMessage')


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStatusBar(MyStatusBar(self))
```

Note that the above code will only work properly if you **never** use other timers created as children of your subclass. If you do that, you may involuntarily reconnect them instead. Take this case:

```
    def showMessage(self, message, timeout=0):
        super().showMessage(message, timeout)
        if timeout:
            timer = self.findChildren(QTimer)[-1]
            timer.timeout.disconnect()
            timer.timeout.connect(self.clearMessage)
            anotherTimer = QTimer(self, interval=3000, 
                timeout=self.myFunction)
            anotherTimer.start()

    def myFunction(self):
        print('my custom function')


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStatusBar(MyStatusBar(self))
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Hello 1', 5000)
        QTimer.singleShot(2000, 
            lambda: self.statusBar().showMessage('Hello 2', 5000))
```

The above will result in the following sequence:

- show a message for 5 seconds;
- start a timer that will timeout after 3 seconds;
- `myFunction()` is called;
- 2 seconds after startup, a new `showMessage()` is called;
- the override finds the last timer (which is the *new* `anotherTimer`), disconnects it, and connects it to `clearMessage()` instead;

While the case above obviously doesn't make a lot of sense, it's better to consider the possibility of other timers created arbitrarily; the solution is quite simple: set an object name for the internal timer and check for it *before* calling the base implementation.

`showMessage()` always creates a new timer if a previous `d->timer` doesn't exist, otherwise it just renews it keeping existing connections intact, so if there was no previous timer with our object name set, we set it, so that we can find it whenever `showMessage()` is called before its timeout and don't reconnect *any* timer again.

Note that I also added the `Qt.FindDirectChildrenOnly` flag to avoid the possibility of finding QTimers coming from other objects (like when using `addWidget()` or `addPermanentWidget()`).

```py
    def showMessage(self, message, timeout=0):
        if timeout:
            oldTimer = self.findChild(QTimer, 'clearMessageTimer',
                Qt.FindDirectChildrenOnly)
        super().showMessage(message, timeout)
        if timeout and not oldTimer:
            # there was no previously set timer
            timer = self.findChildren(
                QTimer, Qt.FindDirectChildrenOnly)[-1]
            timer.setObjectName('clearMessageTimer')
            timer.timeout.disconnect()
            timer.timeout.connect(self.clearMessage)
```

For obvious reasons, this is based on the assumption that the base implementation of `clearMessage()` is **always** called in its override.

Comment: oh, this sounds great, I'm going to try it out. I was trying to find out if there was a way from python to access d->timer, looks like this might be it.

Comment: @ErwanLeroy well, it's more of a workaround, but it's effective. Note that I updated the answer, as I realized that there is the possibility of other timers added *before* the `showMessage` timer times out. With the updated code, there should be no possibility of confusion and involuntary disconnection of other timers.